# For all x in {1,2,3}, x is bigger than 4

Tags: list-manipulation, logic, forall

I am new to `ForAll` or `Exists` command.

```
Resolve[ForAll[x, Element[x, Reals], x > 4]]
```

gives False, because 'every real number is bigger than 4' is false.

But

```
Resolve[ForAll[x, Element[x, {1, 2, 3}], x > 4]]
```

gives 'Unable to Resolve', and

```
Resolve[ForAll[x, MemberQ[{1,2,3},x], x > 4]]
```

gives True.

Q1) Why did the 2nd,3rd codes produce meaningless result ?

Q2) In dealing with ForAll, what is a proper approach to restrict the domain of variable
with user defined list (finte list)?

Q3) How can I express

> Every element of {1,2,3} is bigger than 4

in mathematica and see its truth value is false?

Q4) Help file says :

[image][image]

Restricts *dom* pretty strictly.

Then, can I say any codes containing a phrase like

```
Element[x, {1,2,3}]
```

are completely meaningless?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my  explanation of the result of `Resolve[ForAll[x, MemberQ[{1,2,3},x], x > 4]]`. The command `MemberQ[{1,2,3},x]` itself correctly results in `False` (see the documentation for more details). Therefore, in fact, you ask

```
ForAll[x,False,x > 4]
```

The subexpression `x,False`in the above means `x` belongs to the empty set which  has any property, so

```
 ForAll[x,False,x > 4]
```

correctly performs `True`.
The correct syntax is

```
Resolve[ForAll[x, MemberQ[{1, 2, 3}, x] && x > 4]]
```

> `False`

Addition. And/Or

```
Resolve[ForAll[x, MemberQ[{1, 2, 3}, x] && x > 4], Integers]
```

> `False`

Comment: The command `Resolve[ForAll[x, MemberQ[{1, 2, 3}, x], y^2]]` results in `True`, confirming my explanation. One may replace `y^2` by any syntactically correct expression.

Answer (score 0):

You want to express the condition on $ x $ in a way that `ForAll` understands, and as [@user64494 explains](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/244189/531), `MemberQ` does not do that. However, there are other ways of expressing the condition. Consider:

```
Resolve@ForAll[x, 1 <= x <= 3, x > 4] 
(* False *)
```

However, this does what you expect when you change the final expression:

```
Resolve@ForAll[x, x \[Element] Integers && 1 <= x <= 3, x < 4]
(* True *)
```

It would be nice if Mathematica had a concise notation for stating something is a member of a finite set but I don't know of one.

Answer (score 0):

**How can I express Every element of {1,2,3} is bigger than 4 in mathematica and see its truth value is false?**

```
 AllTrue[{1, 2, 3} - 4, Positive]
```

> False

Comment: I think this is not it: `Point` and an integer number are different things.

Comment: It is not working at least in v12.2.
Error : Resolve::ivar: x>4 is not a valid variable.

Comment: Probably I tested my previous answer without clean nb, and x has some set value. Does my edited answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

For Q3) this is similar to @Pillsy's answer but rather than use inequalities, allows you to put in arbitrary integers from a list.

```
(* Make a function that determines set membership *)
fromset[list_] := Or @@ (Equal[x, #] & /@ list)

(* Use the condition argument in ForAll *)
Resolve[
  ForAll[x, fromset[{1, 2, 3}], x > 4],
 Integers]
```